# VS Code Path does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to execute a simple c++ program in vs code. when I compile the program it is ok however, when I try to execute the file I get error message cannot find path because it does nor exist. doest anyone know what I am doing wrong, it seems as though I am following the tutorial correctly?

Comment: Just check where your compiled program is located and where you're running it from

Answer (score 1):

I know my response is late, but I'm hoping it can help someone in the future. My solution to this was updating my `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` directory. In the "args" section of the task I replaced `"${file}"` with `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"`

This change tells g++ to compile all of the .cpp files in the directory, rather than just the file you're currently working with, which is necessary when you begin introducing other files that main.cpp depends on.

Thanks, I hope anyone reading is having an amazing day, and I apologize for any inaccuracies that may be in this answer. Additionally, I have posted my full `tasks.json` below for anybody that wants to just copy paste

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```